# Conditional Formatting to compare the minute value between two cells

Tags: datetime, if-statement, google-sheets, time, conditional-formatting

I have a spreadsheet that has two values; "Show Start" time (eg 20:30) and "Off Sale" time (eg: 20:25)

I'm using a large amount of data to check these values are set as they should be.

I'm looking to set a conditional format, to show if the "Off Sale" time is anything but exactly 5 minutes before the "Show Start" time, to check that shows are set to come off sale 5 minutes before the show starts.

EG:

| Show Start | Off Sale |
| --- | --- |
| 20:30 | 18:55 |
| 19:00 | 18:55 |

Link to an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NU-F9io67d5eFOf2N1eV00W0_kT-KRSGPbRHPAc4PPk/edit?usp=sharing)

I am limited with how much I can change the data from hour:time format, as other users need to read the sheet in hour & time format

Tried a variety of conditional formatting custom formulas, less than / greater than values, but I'm not familiar with using hour & date formats enough to subtract 5 minutes from the Show Start value for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=(B3+"0:05")=A3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this in **conditional formatting** format rules

```
=ROUND(A3-B3*1,10)=ROUND((1/24/60)*5,10)
```

[image]